# Check whether all return types and argument types are added in php files (using IDE Eclipse)

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

I would like to have a way to check our `php` scripts for missing types in functions/methods.

In the class below, the first method has typed arguments and a return type. The second doesn't:

```
<?php 
class MyClass{
    function alter_string(string $a_string): string{
        return $a_string;
    }
    function alter_another_string($a_string){
        return $a_string;
    }
}
```

Is there some way to check all return types and argument types are added? I am using Eclipse for PHP Developers as IDE. But any other solution would be nice too.

I could write my own script that reads the php files and checks each `function` for a return type. And if there are arguments to the function, that script checks whether the types are added to these arguments. But I am pretty sure there is some existing way to achieve this.

Comment: IDEs like PhpStorm can do this type of check.

Comment: I figured that would be the case. I update my answer since I am using Eclipse. Maybe someone knows how to achieve this with that IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use something like the following:

```
<?php

function check_types($file_path) {
  $file_contents = file_get_contents($file_path);
  $tokens = token_get_all($file_contents);

  $functions = [];
  foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if ($token[0] == T_FUNCTION) {
      $function_name = $token[1];
      $function_args = [];

      for ($i = 3; $i < count($token); $i++) {
        if ($token[$i][0] == T_VARIABLE) {
          $function_args[] = $token[$i][1];
        }
      }

      $functions[$function_name] = $function_args;
    }
  }

  foreach ($functions as $function_name => $function_args) {
    if (!isset($function_args['return'])) {
      echo "Missing return type for function $function_name\n";
    }

    foreach ($function_args as $arg_name => $arg_type) {
      if ($arg_type == '') {
        echo "Missing type for argument $arg_name in function $function_name\n";
      }
    }
  }
}

check_types(__FILE__);
```

You may also use PHPStan in this case.